# SSRS query to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have query consists with right function in SSRS but I need to use the same logic in Oracle SQL and I can't seem to find an solution to find a function in oracle which uses same as RIGHT function.
This is my SSRS query

```
case
    when termnum = substring(dialnum,2,6) and len(dialnum) = '11' then` right(dialnum,10) 
    when termnum = right(dialnum,4) and len(dialnum) = '11' then right(dialnum,10) 
    when termnum = right(dialnum,4) and len(dialnum) = '10' then dialnum
    when termnum = right(dialnum,5) and len(dialnum) = '11' the right(dialnum,10)
    when termnum = right(dialnum,7) and len(dialnum) = '10' then dialnum
    else null 
end new_termnum
```

I need to change this to Oracle.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Once you change the RIGHT(text, int) to SUBSTR(text, -int) you will also need to change len() to length(), and compare it to a number - not a quoted string enclosing the value of the number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using right(dialnum,10) 
try: substr(dialnum,-10)

I hope this helps. 
Mark
https://sqlreports.wordpress.com/

Comment: Indeed, it helped. Thank You for your help.